# Exculde Columns on Group BY

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a query below my only problem is to exclude some column in the group by clause.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
(server, 
''select 
    b.devdate as DevDate,   
    c.devWidth AS DevWitdh,
    c.devHeight as DevHeight,
    a.devQty AS DevQTY,     
    c.devCode AS DevCode,
    d.devdesk AS DevDesc,

 from 
    server.a_STAT a,
    server.a_cust b,
    server.a_post c,
    server.dev_date d,
    server.a_adress e
 where 
       a. DevQTY!=0 and a.AUF_NR=b.AUF_NR and a.auf_pos = c.auf_pos AND
       b.AUF_NR=c.AUF_NR AND 
       b.AUF_OFF = 0 AND  
       d.idnr=  c.GLAS1  AND    
       b. dev_date ''''' + @DTFrom + ''''' AND '''''+ @DTTo+'''''   '


SET @ENDTSQLSTATEMENT1 =' GROUP BY b. dev_date,c.GLAS1, d.gl_bez, c. DevWitdh, c. DevHeight , a. DevQTY ORDER BY b. dev_date '' )'
```

In my select I want to add the Customer name and the Project but I don't want to include that in the group by clause. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Not possible I am afraid!

Think about it: if you have a table:

```
foos   bars
-----  -----
foo1   bar1
foo2   bar2
foo2   bar3
```

were you to run "`select foos,bars from foobars group by  foos` " which bars value would it display for "foo2"?

You can get around thus by coding an aggregate function such as `MAX(bars)` which would give you `"foo2  bar3"` which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you'll gona need 2 queries to do this.
Like in the post bellow:

```
select e.empID, fname, lname, title, dept, projectIDCount
from
(
   select empID, count(projectID) as projectIDCount
   from employees E left join projects P on E.empID = P.projLeader
   group by empID
) idList
inner join employees e on idList.empID = e.empID
```

[T-SQL GROUP BY: Best way to include other grouped columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626788/t-sql-group-by-best-way-to-include-other-grouped-columns)