# Sql join two tables with having clause

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables

```
First_id | Text    Second_id | First_id | Date | Email
```

I need to get all records from first table having count from second table with date null and email null.

I have sql:

```
Select * from first f join second s on f.id = s.first_id where date is null and email is null group by first_id having(count(s.id) < 10 or count(s.id) = 0)
```

It works well, but where I have all data and email filled on second table for id from first table I got no result.

Sample data:
First table

```
1 | one
2 | two
```

Second table

```
1 | 1 | NULL | NULL
1 | 1 | 2015-01-01 | NULL
1 | 2 | 2015-01-01 | NULL
1 | 2 | 2015-01-01 | NULL
```

I expect on output:

```
1 | one | 1
2 | two | 0
```

last column is count of entries from second with date and email NULL. My query returns

```
1 | one | 1
```

No second row

Comment: *"I need to get all records from first table having count from second table with date null and email null."*: I don't understand. So what are you trying to count exactly?  Consider posting sample input and output data to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

Do a left join, also it's good to specify which columns you want to show, otherwise you will get duplicates.

```
Select * from first f left join second s on f.id = s.first_id where date is null and email is null group by first_id having(count(s.id) < 10 or count(s.id) = 0)
```

Comment: it's ok but it doesn't show counter with number of rows = 0

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.First_id, t2.Second_id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.First_id = t2.First_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Second_id
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY Second_id
    HAVING (COUNT(*) < 10 OR COUNT(*) = 0)
) _cc
ON t.Second_id = _cc.Second_id
WHERE t2.date IS NULL AND t2.email IS NULL;
```

A solution is to check the HAVING restrictions in a subquery that returns the ids you need for the rest joins.

When you use the GROUP BY statement it is good to select only the GROUP BY column or an aggregate function otherwise you might have unpredictable results.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html

[How to include other grouped columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626788/t-sql-group-by-best-way-to-include-other-grouped-columns)